# Can one IP address correspond to multiple ASNs

Tags: ip, bgp, anycast

Can one IP address correspond to multiple ASNs?
If so, what were the circumstances? Is it related to anycast ip address?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, each IP address is associated with a unique origin ASN.  You could however have a more specific prefix from a different ASN.  For example, 189.50.192.0/20 => ASN1 and 189.50.192.0/22 => ASN2.

All anycast locations would need to be originated from the same ASN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a Multi Origin AS (MOAS). Here is a brief explanation to a stack readers:

To exchange reachability information about IP addresses,
different Autonomous Systems (ASes) in the Internet use BGP. In BGP, each IP address prefix (i.e., collection of IP
addresses) is usually originated by a single AS. There are,
however, also cases where multiple ASes originate the same
prefix, this prefix is in turn called a Multi Origin AS (MOAS)
prefix. Network operators use MOAS prefixes to e.g., provide
resilience, load balancing, and multi-homing.

Further details: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.08490.pdf
Proof of concept:
https://bgp.he.net/report/multi-origin-routes#_ipv4multioriginroutes 
https://stat.ripe.net/ui2013/193.104.254.82#tabId=routing

Must mention though that it's not recommended to do, but it terms of the question, it's possible and present all over the internet.